# Why does arp -a only show some machines on my network?

Tags: linux, arp

I ran `arp -a` on a Linux server, and this is the output:

```
[root@trnsrv1 ~]# arp -a
? (10.223.8.82) at 00:50:56:B5:75:08 [ether] on bond0
? (10.223.11.254) at E0:5F:B9:66:A6:00 [ether] on bond0
```

10.223.11.254 - this is the gateway

10.223.8.82 - this is another server, and it is not the only one on the LAN.

Why did it appear and others did not?

Answer (score 9):

> Why did it appear and others did not?

Because those were the only two machines which had exchanged network traffic with your server within the last 60 seconds, or whatever arp cache value is specified on your system in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/default/gc_stale_time`, if different from the default of 60.

`arp -a` reports what is in the arp cache; it does not make any attempt to populate the cache with as many entries as possible.

Comment: For the Op: one might ping the broadcast address to get all connected devices in the subnet; but, if the ping traverses a gateway, then only the gateway arp entry is revealed, not the devices on the other side of the gateway.

Comment: I am getting different answers on different machines connected to same network so other answers are possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know a little about arp caches before you can effectively interpret the output of an arp cache

The arp cache contains **IP:MAC Address** mappings for:

- Hosts your server exchanged traffic **WITHIN IT'S OWN SUBNET**
- Router interfaces used to route traffic between your host and others in **DIFFERENT subnets**

The arp cache of these **IP**:**MAC Address** mappings do **NOT** survive:

- **Networking** restart.
- **Server** reboot.

Although *Garbage Collection* ("***gc***") ***should*** purge these mappings in your arp cache that exceed the specified **GC** threshold, the reality is they persist, albeit recorded as "***stale***"

So you won't see an ***IP:MAC*** mapping of a host your server exchanged traffic with that's addressed on a ***DIFFERENT*** subnet, or even one within your host's own subnet if the networking or server itself was restarted.

BTW, if you want to test the persistence of mappings beyond the ***GC*** interval, `ping` another host within the same subnet and after stopping the `ping` periodically execute:

```
ip -statistics neighbour
```

You'll see the **IP:MAC Address** for the host you `ping`'ed remains past the **GC** interval.